# What are All Possible Variables for a List View Filter?

Tags: 2010, list-view, filter, ootb

In List Settings for a list you have the option to filter the list; there are variables such as `[Me]` and `[Today]`.

Are there any others?  What are they?

*(I've searched the world over for such a list and could not discover it)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no other options as such. but you can use calculated columns as an alternate solution which will have most of the excel based features.

Comment: Really?  That's it?  Just those two variables?

Comment: Those are the only dynamic variables, all other standard filtering options still apply.